# When initializing Drawer.Navigator the drawer is blinking, though in parameters I pass openByDefault={ false }

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, drawer

react-navigation v5

When initializing Drawer.Navigator the drawer is blinking, though in parameters I pass openByDefault={ false } How to get out of this blinking?

"@react-navigation/drawer": "5.8.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "5.5.1."

[image]

Update:

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Drawer.Navigator
    openByDefault={ false }
    drawerContent={ (props) => <CustomDrawerContent { ...props } /> }
    drawerContentOptions={ drawerOptions }
  >
    { isAuth ? (
      <>
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Dashboard"
          component={ DashboardStack }
          options={ {
            drawerIcon: config => <DashboardIcon fill={ 'white' }/>
          } }
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="Logout"
          component={ LogoutStack }
          options={ {
            drawerIcon: config => <LogoutIcon fill={ 'white' }/>
          } }
        />
      </>) : (
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Authorization"
        component={ LoginScreen }
      />
    ) }
  </Drawer.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

```js
const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={ { flex: 1 } }>
            <View style={ {
                height: 60,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                opacity: 0.9,
                paddingVertical: 10
            } }>
                <Logo height={ 30 } width={ 165 }/>
            </View>
            <View style={ { height: 3, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#000', opacity: 0.9 } }>
                <Divider style={ { height: 1, width: 255, marginHorizontal: 30, backgroundColor: 'gray', opacity: 0.9 } }/>
            </View>
            <ScrollView style={ { backgroundColor: '#000', opacity: 0.9, paddingTop: 20 } }>
                <DrawerItemList { ...props } />
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Added an initialization code

Comment: Could you please add it as text inside code tags? Makes it easier for others to work with.

Comment: Added as a code

Comment: Same problem when using it with `react-native-web`. I blinks with a semi-transparent black screen on top of all the rendered elements.

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed it by using a hook to check for the initial render**

```
const useInitialRender = () => {
    const [isInitialRender, setIsInitialRender] = React.useState(false)

    if (!isInitialRender) {
        setTimeout(() => setIsInitialRender(true), 1)
        return true
    }
    return false
}

const MyApp = () => {
const isInitialRender = useInitialRender()

return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator 
        openByDefault={false}
        drawerStyle={{ width: isInitialRender ? null : "70%" }}
        drawerContent={ (props) => <CustomDrawerContent { ...props } /> }>

          <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={ MainScreen } /> 
      
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
)}
```

Comment: Just a wait of 1 ms is good. I wonder why that behavior exists with React Native Drawer Navigation. Maybe they use an async await inside the module for a fast operation, that causes the app to synchronously block the rendering.